# Generate python unicode character from int value

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

For example, I want subscript 0: `u"\u2080"`, but I want the `2080` to come from a variable. How can I achieve this? doing something like `u"\u%d"%var` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
number = 0x2080 # = 8320 in decimal
unicode_char = unichr(number)
print unicode_char
# output: ₀
```

and reverse the process:

```
number = ord(unicode_char)
print 'number = {0:d} = 0x{0:04x}'.format(number)
# output: number = 8320 = 0x2080
```

Comment: This does not seem to work: `unichr(2080)` turns into `u'\u0820'`. I assume because the `ord()` is not the same as the code inside

Comment: @Ryan `2080` is a hex value. Use `unichr(int(str(2080), 16))` or something.

Comment: you need to give the number in hex: `unichr(0x2080)`

Comment: `'{:04x}'.format(ord(u'\u2080'))` and this is how you the the number back as hex string.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: it would be nice if you edited your answer to include what you have added here in the comments, since it is important to fully understand what to do.